# Convert String to Structure (Byte)

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, stringstream

I using the gcrypt **struct gcry_sexp_t** (https://fossies.org/dox/libgcrypt-1.6.3/structgcry__sexp.html) that I define as **typedef gcry_sexp_t Blob**.

I get a string such as **0069c570** and convert it to a Blob (0x69c570)

1. Convert String to HEX
2. Place hex string into vector
3. Attempt Convert to Blob (memcpy, vector iterator, cast)

The attempts to use memcpy, iterators or cast have not worked. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this task?

```
    // Convert to Hex String
    std::stringstream vstream;
    vstream << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
    for (size_t i = 0; size > i; ++i) {
        vstream << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(value[i]));
    }
    std::string valuestr = vstream.str();
    valuestr.replace(0, 2, "0x");

    // Place into std::vector
    std::transform(valuestr.begin(), valuestr.end(), valuestr.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::vector<char> bytes(valuestr.begin(), valuestr.end());
    bytes.push_back('\0');
    char *rcvdblob = (char *)&bytes[0];

    // Attempt to convert to Blob
    Blob rcvdpayload;
    memcpy(&rcvdpayload, &bytes[0], sizeof(rcvdpayload));

    for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = bytes.begin(); it != bytes.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
     }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    rcvdpayload = *reinterpret_cast<Blob*>(rcvdblob);
```

Comment: If there was ever a problem that could be solved more clearly, concisely and faster in C than C++, this is the poster child for it.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
std::string valuestr = vstream.str();
valuestr.replace(0, 2, "0x");
```

overwrites your first hex. Are you sure you want to do this ?

This

```
std::transform(valuestr.begin(), valuestr.end(), valuestr.begin(), ::tolower);
std::vector<char> bytes(valuestr.begin(), valuestr.end());
bytes.push_back('\0');
char *rcvdblob = (char *)&bytes[0];
```

Is completely unnecessary since **(1)** you know that your string is only composed of lower case hex chars and the letter 'x' and **(2)** you get access to a continues sequence of '\0' terminated char by using `valuestr.c_str()`

Here

```
memcpy(&rcvdpayload, &bytes[0], sizeof(rcvdpayload));
```

you end up copying one byte since `gcry_sexp` is declared as.

```
struct gcry_sexp { 
    byte d[1];  // I assume byte is typedefed  as unsigned char or such
};
```

It might be that d[] is larger in concrete cases. I guess the struct is just a place holder for an array which might be at least of size 1. Not an uncommon practice but of course not 100% typesafe one might say.

Comment: You're correct. I declare 2 **Blob** (gcry_sexp_t) structures and copy them via memcpy (**memcpy(&rcvdpayload, &encpayload, sizeof(Blob));**). I can then use a function such as **gcry_sexp_dump** to validate that the content is the same. I then simplified everything to performing a memcpy on valuestr using **memcpy(&rcvdpayload, valuestr.c_str(), sizeof(Blob));**. The valuestr.c_str() has for example the text:**00696f30**. After the memcpy the **Blob rcvdpayload** has the value **0x3033663639363030** that is the hex representation but in the reverse order. I'll need to work on this issue.